# Calling a function inside a function not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create an image animation for the first time (it is probably pretty awful, but that is beside the point of this question). So I need to call the function displayPicture from within buttonPressed. I am able to display the picture if I put the commands all within the buttonPressed function. Now that I want to call the other function, it doesn't do anything. Including the alert (which I put there for the purpose of debugging).

HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr><td><img src="images/jar.png" /><tr/></td>
    <tr><td><button onclick="buttonPressed()" id="button" name="plus1" type="button">
        <h2>JAAAAAAR</h2></button></td></tr>
    <script src="java_script.js"></script>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var width=700;
var height=1050;
var img = document.createElement("img");
var table = document.getElementById('table');

function buttonPressed(){
    img.src = "images/clair_jar.jpg";
    while(width > 480 && height > 720){
        width = width-22;
        height = height-33;
        displayPicture(src, width, height);
        setInterval(displayPicture(src, width, height), 100);
    }
}

function displayPicture(src, newWidth, newHeight){
    alert("blah");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    img.width = newWidth;
    img.height = newHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `src` of `displayPicture()` is not defined anywhere I think you want to pass `img.src` something like

should be

```
displayPicture(img.src, width, height);
```

instead of

```
displayPicture(src, width, height);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function calls are passing src, but it looks like you mean to pass img.src.  You should be seeing an undefined error on src.